# Unanchored comments pushed through Google Drive API v3 do not reflect on the document UI

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, google-docs

I am trying the Google Drive API v3 for a project.

I need to push comments onto a document on the drive via NodeJS. I was able to add unanchored comments on a Goggle Doc type document. I can see the comment in the comment history like this:

[image: Google Doc Type Comment]

I do know I cannot add anchored comments to such a file. But I would also like to add unanchored & anchored comments to files of word format (not Google Doc Type), as supported in the Google Drive API v3. Unfortunately my added comments, via NodeJS, are been saved to the document history (I can retrieve them via drive.comments.list) but are not been reflected on the document UI like in the above picture.

It shows like :

[image: Word style doc]

My new comment also reflects on the thumbnail of the document in the drive as "You just commented"

[image: My Drive]

My code in NodeJS:

```
function addCommenttoDoc(comment) {

    drive.comments.create({
      "fileId": "1V6boIoUuXjMzSZ4SFESxFBZUmCOu001C",
      "fields": "*",
      "resource": {
        "content": comment,
      }
    })
        .then(function(response) {
                // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
                console.log("Response >>>>> ", response);
              },
              function(err) { console.error("Execute error >>>>>>", err); });
  }
```

Also, comments made via Doc viewer directly (UI) DO NOT get returned in the drive.comments.list in case of the Word file type.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I apologize, this is my first time on adding a question on a public forum. I was not aware regarding the rules of such phrases.